# Halving an Image with Pixels

Tags: c, pixel

I am getting a segmentation fault when I use this method in another program. I've confirmed my pointers are correct and that the issue is certainly within this function. I'm assuming I'm trying to access memory that I don't actually have access to. A solution to my problem would be appreciated

```
uint8_t* half( const uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows ) {

int length = ((floor(cols/2)) * (floor(rows/2))); // change when we must ignore odd rows/cols
uint8_t* newimg = malloc(length * sizeof(uint8_t)); 
memset( newimg, 0, length);
int count = 0;
for(unsigned int c = 0; c < cols; c+=2){    
    for(unsigned int r = 0; r < rows; r+=2){
         uint8_t first = array[(c - 1) + ((r - 1) * cols)];
         uint8_t second = array[c + ((r - 1) * cols)];
         uint8_t third = array[(c - 1) + (r * cols)];
         uint8_t fourth = array[c + (r * cols)]; 
         uint8_t mean = (first + second + third + fourth)/4;
        newimg[count] = mean;
        count++;
            } 
} 

return newimg;

}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: it's giving em no indication something is wrong, however something obviously is when a seg fault is printed when it compiles

Comment: You don't need to use `floor`. For non-negative integers, `n/2` is the same as `floor(0.5 * n)`.

Comment: i used floor for the sake of restricting the size of ym new image, it is to ignore an odd number of rows or sides

Comment: I don't think your sarcasm will make me a better learner or programmer @Jongware

Comment: You can't say I missed the same thing twice. okay, my bad. I miss interpreted, I was wrong, please stop insulting me for the sake of insulting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. First of all, I had a seg fault because I started from the wrong part of the first array and during the first iteration I would subtract one from the index and go out of the bounds of the array. Secondly, I was drawing the new image in the wrong order, which was remedied by switching the order of  my for loop headers, I was drawing down the image instead of along it and my produced image looked like a pixeled mess. My code now works, thank you for the input eveyrone

Answer (score 1):

Think what happens in this code when `c` or `r` is `0`:

```
uint8_t first = array[(c - 1) + ((r - 1) * cols)];
uint8_t second = array[c + ((r - 1) * cols)];
uint8_t third = array[(c - 1) + (r * cols)];
```

In the `0,0` case you are trying to access the `-1-cols`, `-cols`, and `-1` elements of the array which is most likely out-of-bounds.

Comment: this advice resolved my seg fault, i changed where the for loops began in their counting. the point of this method was to take an image and make it smaller, when the image is printed, it is a pixeled mess of the original image, so one problem is solved, but here iis another i'd appreciate help with. Somethign wrong with my algoritm

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? It looks like you are resizing the size of an image by 50% by averaging the pixels. What colour format are the pixels in (RGB, palette index, etc...)?

Comment: you are right, I'm halving the image. I believe it is RGB

Comment: I would create another question regarding this then as it can get a little complicated depending on the exact RGB format. Short version: your method of averaging would only work for gray scale images and has an overflow issue at that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe is caused in this part

```
     uint8_t first = array[(c - 1) + ((r - 1) * cols)];
     uint8_t second = array[c + ((r - 1) * cols)];
     uint8_t third = array[(c - 1) + (r * cols)];
     uint8_t fourth = array[c + (r * cols)]; 
     uint8_t mean = (first + second + third + fourth)/4;
```

where the result of the calculation may be larger the it should be , to check this print the result of the calculation using `printf` and check if it doesn't surpass the array size